# Live Preview is jumping to top of page on edit

Tags: live-preview

When using the live preview pane, each time I type something or move a block, the preview pane jumps to the top. When editing anywhere but the top, this is not ideal. Is this a bug? I also checked it on a previous site that I had built in Craft and I'm getting the same behavior.

Comment: As per my answer I have voted to close this as off topic as I feel this is a bug with Craft, and not a question the community can assist any further with.

Answer (score 1):

I have also noticed this happening, but the Craft Stack Exchange is not the best place to post about potential bugs/issues.

It might be worth submitting a bug report to support@pixelandtonic.com as they are best suited to take things from here!